# Relativistic Turning: Most efficient strategy?

Tags: special-relativity, space-travel

Say I have a ship that can go something like 99.999997% C, and has a very, very large amount of energy at its disposal (essentially beamed to the ship from elsewhere), but not unlimited. I want to conserve my energy usage.

I have to follow a zig-zag track to drop off Alice, Bob, Charlie, and Darla at star systems A, B, C, and D in order. I'm Eddie, and I'm eventually headed for system E.

**Is it more efficient to ramp up to and back down from my max velocity at each system to make my turns, or would it be less energy intensive to just accelerate in a different direction while at speed** and kick folks off in shuttles as I cruise by the intermediate systems? Would gravity assists work at those velocities?

Here's a rough map.

```
Start              B
                                D
           C
E                                                  
                       A
```

Mostly this situation is constructed to help define the question: in relativistic travel, is it cheaper to travel only in straight lines, or turn by vectoring thrust?

Comment: Can you use the gravity of the drop-off systems as a mechanism to change your angular momentum (but keep your speed roughly constant in the system rest frame)?  If so, then the most energy efficient approach is to use the gravity of the system to turn.  Changing direction when you are going slightly below c would be outrageously expensive, energy-wise.

Comment: What I really want to know is if that turn is more or less expensive than slowing down and speeding back up again, because it does take a heck of a lot of energy to get there in the first place, right?

Comment: Turning is basically just changing angular momentum while slowing down and speeding up are changing total kinetic energy.  I am guessing the latter is more expensive.

Comment: I feel that turning is always more convenient as it implies the use of part of the already spent energy and this should be true even in SR. However if one could use gravitational assist it might be required to slow down in order to leave the assisting body with the wanted aim.